# Linker issue with DirectShow base class in mingw 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, linker, mingw-w64

After porting a project from visual studio to mingw. I am getting the following linker error

```
undefined reference to `g_Templates'
undefined reference to `g_cTemplates'
```

The code which it points to looks something like this

```
#include <tchar.h>
#endif // DEBUG
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <combase.h>

extern CFactoryTemplate g_Templates[];
extern int g_cTemplates;

HINSTANCE g_hInst;
DWORD     g_amPlatform;     // VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS etc... (from GetVersionEx)
OSVERSIONINFO g_osInfo;

//
// an instance of this is created by the DLLGetClassObject entrypoint
// it uses the CFactoryTemplate object it is given to support the
// IClassFactory interface

class CClassFactory : public IClassFactory, public CBaseObject
{

private:
    const CFactoryTemplate *const m_pTemplate;
    ...
public:
    CClassFactory(const CFactoryTemplate *);

    // IUnknown
    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, __deref_out void ** ppv);
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG)AddRef();
    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG)Release();

    // IClassFactory
    STDMETHODIMP CreateInstance(LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter, REFIID riid, __deref_out void **pv);
    STDMETHODIMP LockServer(BOOL fLock);

    // allow DLLGetClassObject to know about global server lock status
    static BOOL IsLocked() {
        return (m_cLocked > 0);
    };
};

// --- COM entrypoints -----------------------------------------
//
//  Call any initialization routines
//
void DllInitClasses(BOOL bLoading)
{
    // traverse the array of templates calling the init routine
    // if they have one
    for (i = 0; i < g_cTemplates; i++) //<---------Cannot recognize this symbol
    {
        const CFactoryTemplate * pT = &g_Templates[i];
        if (pT->m_lpfnInit != NULL)
        {
            (*pT->m_lpfnInit)(bLoading, pT->m_ClsID);
        }
    }

}
....
....
```

I have been searching on this issue for a while and have not made any progress. It seems that that this symbol exists in `strmbasd.lib` (debug version) and is generated from DirectShow base classes. I generated `strmbasd.lib` using mingw64 however I am still getting this linker error. I wanted to know if there was any other approach I could try .

Comment: What is CFactoryTemplate? Is it user defined? or it is a built in class?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Direct Show for Microsoft Visual C++. And found no such issue. Microsoft SDK provides the libraries and headers as well as the base classes. You may want to check the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407279(v=vs.85).aspx). I haven't used MingW, so I don't know about the issue of MingW. You may try it in MSVC, MSDN provides some handful informations and references for Direct Show. Please check the previous link mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your including dllentry.cpp/dllsetup.cpp from DirectShow BaseClasses assumes that you develop a filter library and you are expected to define template symbols in your code ([example](https://github.com/roman380/gdcl.co.uk-mpeg4/blob/master/mp4demux/mp4demux.cpp#L22)) to satisfy linker.

If you don't see how your code is referencing factories, you can define fake array and `g_cTemplates` of zero to pass through, however eventually there is something that makes linker drag these symbols into output.